# How to modify the wordpress menus' structure

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to insert in anchor's menu some divs that contain a wp page.
One of anchor menu has a submenu that contain 5 link. Each of these link contains a page (wp page).

I followed this post: http://bit.ly/MIRtcY
But is not a specific source and I have some problem to obtain what I want.

Have you a specific url or some suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different solutions and now I working with walker nav menu.
This is the code:

```
  // Class to insert div and page into nav menu (not working yet)
 class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
  {
  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
  {
       global $wp_query;
       $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

       $class_names = $value = '';

       $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

       $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
       $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

       $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

       $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

       // $prepend = '<strong>';
       // $append = '</strong>';
       $description  = empty( $item->description ) ? '<div class="dropEverything-page"><div class="dropEverything-row">'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</div></div>' : '';

       if($depth != 0)
       {
                 $description = $append = $prepend = "";
       }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
        $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }
 }
```

I modified this line:

```
       // I need to get the ID of the page and put it into the anchor
       $postID = get_page_by_title("Profile")->ID;
   $post = get_post(&$postID);
       $description  = empty( $item->description ) ? '<div class="dropEverything-page"><div class="dropEverything-row">'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</div></div>' : '';
```

I need to substitute

```
esc_attr( $item->description )
```

with

```
esc_attr( echo apply_filters("the_content", $post->post_content) )
```

but the website return me a blank page.

Any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: I solved this problem without "echo". I changed the last line:

      esc_attr( apply_filters("the_content", $post->post_content) )

It's all ok, but the page "Press" don't shows the wp gallery. Only the title is shown and nothing else.